# HTTP Post using perl script returns 503 service unavailable while using proxy

Tags: perl, proxy, http-post, http-proxy

HTTP Post using perl script returns 503 service unavailable while using proxy

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
use LWP::UserAgent;     
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;    
$ua->timeout( 20 );    
my $server_endpoint = "https://mytest.test.com/events";    
$ua->proxy('https' , "http://1.2.3.4:8088");    
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);    
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');    
$req->authorization_basic('user1', 'user1pass123!');    
print "Posting URL: $server_endpoint \n";    
# add POST data to HTTP request body    
my $post_data = '{"events":[{"signature":"my_test_box:application:Network","source_id":"1.2.3.4","manager":"my_manager_srv","source":"my_test_box_2","class":"application","type":"Network","severity":3,"description":"high network utilization in application A"}]}';    
$req->content($post_data);    
my $resp = $ua->request($req);    
if ($resp->is_success) 
  {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
    print "HTTP POST code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
```

1. Posting to any other data receiver URL is fine via same proxy and same script. (URLs configured on proxy to allow traffic)
2. Able to post data using curl command to: https://mytest.test.com/events ..however while using this script returns 503 service unavailable
   3.Tested using the same script to same URL on my local machine without proxy and posting works fine.

Any help highly appreciated
Thanks.

Adding command curl and output here:

```
#curl -u user1:user1pass123! mytest.test.com/events -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"events":[{"signature":"my_test_box:application:Network","‌​source_id":"1.2.3.4"‌​,"manager":"my_manag‌​er_srv","source":"my‌​_test_box_2","class"‌​:"application","type‌​":"Network","severit‌​y":3,"description":"‌​high network utilization in application A"}]}'; -v -x http://1.2.3.4:8088
* About to connect() to proxy 1.2.3.4 port 8088 (#0) 
* Trying 1.2.3.4... connected 
* Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) port 8088 (#0) 
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to mytest.test.com:443 
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user1' 
> CONNECT mytest.test.com:443 HTTP/1.1 
> Host: mytest.test.com:443 
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive 
> Content-Type: application/json 
> < HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established < 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request 
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb 
* CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none 
* Server certificate: 
* subject: CN=*.test.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
* start date: Nov 01 22:33:00 2017 GMT 
* expire date: Nov 01 22:33:00 2018 GMT 
* common name: .test.com 
* issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.",L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US 
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user1' > POST /events HTTP/1.1 
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 
> Host: mytest.test.com 
> Accept: */ 
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 325 
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 08:38:23 GMT < Content-Length: 101 < Connection: keep-alive 
< Server: nginx 
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; always 
< {"response"{"processed":1,"cached":0,"received":1},"success‌":true,"message":"Pro‌cessed 1 event(s)"} 
* Connection #0 to host 1.2.3.4 left intact 
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Please make sure that you are using at least version 6.06 of LWP when using proxy for https URL's since on older versions the support was broken.  Also, please provide the versions of LWP you are using and the full response instead of only the response code.

Comment: # perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)"
5.833

Comment: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>SSL Certificate Verification Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>SSL Certificate Verification Error (ssl_failed)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A secure SSL session could not be established with the Web Site: "".
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>

Comment: <FONT face="Helvetica">
This is typically caused by a Web Site that is not configured to accept SSL connections, but could be because the Proxy does not trust the Web Site's certificate authority.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: `# perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)" 5.833 ` - so you want help for a version of LWP which is 9 years old? I recommend that your actually update whatever software stack you have running which is using this long long obsolete version. But anyway - you see from the error message that the problem is certificate validation. Even though this old version of LWP does not do full certificate validation it checks at least the certificate chain and this is not trusted - probably because you are using a self-signed certificate or a certificate from an untrusted CA.

Comment: The data posting is working fine using the same CA  using CURL

Comment: These comments are only badly readable - please edit your question instead to provide these additional details in a nicely formatted readable way. Also *"The data posting is working fine using the same CA using CURL"* - how do you know that? You don't specify a CA store in your Perl program.

Comment: ok..characters are limited and I had to paste in blocks of messages...

Comment: beginning curl command...Closing connection #0 is the output of curl posting...curl is using the CA while posting data ..perl program doesn't need to specify any CA to post data as we have not specified in curl as well

Comment: Again - edit the question to provide such information and don't paste everything into comments. And, just because you don't specify CA store in both cases does not mean that the same CA store is used. Defaults might differ.

Comment: done. edited the question with curl output.

Answer (score 0):

Since the version of Perl you are using is fairly old, you cannot actually set an HTTPS proxy that way. You are forced to do it low-level, via environment variables.

```
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY}='http://1.2.3.4:8088';
```

Note that you **MUST** do it **before** you create your UserAgent.

That aside, you should import the module for SSL connections `IO::Socket::SSL` (`Net::SSL` would be preferrable, but it is most definitevely not available for a version of Perl that old). You can import the module setting a debug level (from 1 to 4, I suggest 3).

To recap, this should be the start of your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY}='http://1.2.3.4:8088';
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG}=1;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
...
```

P.S.: you should also check the response headers you obtain with Perl, instead of curl. Add `print $resp->headers_as_string();` in case `$resp->is_success` is false.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to analyze the problem since you are using a 9 year old (and long obsolete) software stack. But given the response you show in the comments I suspect that not your code is having the SSL problems but your proxy has. To cite from the HTTP response body you got:

> SSL Certificate Verification Error (ssl_failed) ...
>   This is typically caused by a Web Site that is not configured to accept SSL connections, but could be because the Proxy does not trust the Web Site's certificate authority.

Given that you have this problem with LWP but not curl this response might be due to differences on how these clients construct the request to the proxy. If your setup uses IO::Socket::SSL as backend then your old version of LWP will not construct a proper proxy request which might cause this failure (fixed in LWP 6.06 in 2014). If you use Crypt::SSLeay instead missing support for SNI in this old version might be the problem (fixed in 0.59_3 in 2012).

Anyway, I really recommend to move away from your old, unsupported and probably insecure software stack. The problem might simply vanish if you use a current stack.

Comment: yes you are right..let me check the proxy configuration. shouldn't be the issue with LWP as the same script is posting data successfully to other URL receivers